# Validity of "stati Schengen" visa for entering Vienna

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens

I have a South African passport with a "stati Schengen" visa issued by Italy.  The visa is type "C" and is valid for MULT entries.

Can I visit Vienna, flying from Italy, with above visa?  Will it be valid?

Answer (score 12):

Yes. "Stati Schengen" is Italian for "Schengen States," which means that your visa is valid for the entire Schengen area. Austria is a member of the Schengen area, so your visa is valid there.

MULT means that the visa is valid for multiple entries, but this doesn't matter to your question unless you plan to fly through a country that isn't in the Schengen area.

In fact, if you travel entirely within the Schengen area (for example, if you fly direct from Italy to Austria, or if you transit only through other Schengen states), you should not even see any immigration control or other passport checks, unless you encounter "temporary" controls that have been introduced in response to the refugee crisis or some other event, or if you encounter the "non-systematic" controls that are allowed under the Schengen agreement.

This assumes that the visa's expiration date has not passed, of course, and that you have not exceeded the 90 days of presence you are allowed in the 180-day period ending on the date of travel.

Comment: To put it more simply: flying Vienna-Rome is effectively a domestic trip, practically no different from flying Cape Town-Durban. And those temporary border checks, which have been "re-abolished", were only at the land borders

Comment: @Crazydre But the question is about a "stati Schengen" visa, which, if it said anything else, would most likely say "Italia."  With such a visa, it would *not* be permitted to travel to Vienna, regardless of the border checks that may or may not be in place.  (Also, without a systematic check in place, it's still possible for arriving internal Schengen flights to be met by border control officers; this has happened to me on several occasions, and, when it does, they ask to see everyone's passport.  Those from visa-required countries get closer scrutiny, presumably to check their visas.)

Comment: @Crazydre Even if there are no regular immigration control on flights within the Schengen area, it is not particularly appropriate to compare them with domestic flights. Independent of the refugee situation in Europe, you may be up for a random customs check, during which a check of your id or travel documents is also likely.

Comment: @phoog Does that mean the flight lands at a non-Schengen gate on purpose, or that you're met by standing border guards in the Schengen section? Like I said I've been checked at internal land borders (here in Switzerland, despite being in Schengen, internal checks seem to be fairly common at major crossings, even before the crisis) Never at airports though, even during the crisis

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo such checks can be made on (true) domestic flights, too, depending on the law of the country in question, though they would surely be far less likely.

Comment: @Crazydre in my experience, when you get to the end of the jetway, there is a team of border officers asking to see everyone's passport.  This has even happened to me when arriving from *outside* the Schengen area, but it has also happened several times when arriving on an internal Schengen flight; in these cases, the flight arrives at a normal internal Schengen gate.

Comment: @Crazydre, though established for a different reason, the temporary border checks introduced by France also applied to arriving flights from some Schengen destinations. I've seen a (charter) Heraklion-Paris flight where passengers were brought to the non-Schengen arrivals and had to undergo passport checks.

Comment: I have seen the same thing @phoog describes on flights entirely within Schengen: officers asking to see everyone's passport at the jetway. Some passengers were taken aside while their documents were checked, while others were waved through. I've also seen border police come on board the aircraft looking for a few specific individuals before they let the rest of us off (it was quite comical, as I was sitting up front, and the officer didn't know the names of the people he wanted to question, and eventually came back with the names written on his hand).